# What do the images represent?

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge

Can you guess the word hidden in the meaning of these images?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a lady employee gone to office and then everything happened very bad.

Comment: Does the identity of the person in the 4th picture matter at all?

Comment: @BrentHackers Not at all

Answer (score 6):

Second attempt after being bitten earlier

> Vampire

The image connections

> [Vampire woman](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/04/06/mexico-vampire-woman_n_845032.html) an apparently famous lady 
>  [Vampire fire](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18686875-vampire-fire) a novel by J. R. Rain   
>  [Vampire money](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/mychemicalromance/vampiremoney.html) a song by My Chemical Romance  
>  [Kristen Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bella_Swan) played Bella in Twilight became a vampire - inspired by @BrentHackers 
>  Vampire error - an image search gives  [digital artwork](http://thegreatrouge.deviantart.com/art/Fallacy-Vampire-Error-618340956)  
>  [To Sleep with a Vampire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108348/) a movie

First attempt

> Bar

With the images representing

> a(d)dress bar  
>  electric bar fire 
>  bar bill 
>  roll bar - from rolled eyes 
>  error bar 
>  snooze bar  - large button on an alarm clock

Comment: Sounds like the intended answer +1

Comment: Very nice answer..not what I was looking for but +1 from me as well :)

Comment: First one maybe 'Barbie' (doll) too?

Answer (score 3):

> Cold

1

> [Cold shoulder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_shoulder)

2

> Hot & Cold ([Katy Perry song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTHNpusq654), [pain relief](https://www.riteaid.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/220x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/4/041167008430.jpg), or simply opposites)

3

> Cold hard cash (i.e. money)

4

> [Head cold](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/head_cold) (i.e. common cold)

5

> [Cold Unknown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96layhee8B0) (song by Mighty Oaks)

6

> Out cold (meaning asleep or unconscious)

Comment: You're closer than the previews answer..still not what I was looking for..so here's an upvote.

Comment: @Michael I figured 5 was a bit of a stretch.  Then remembered the song relationship to 2 and began to think maybe the `knowledge` tag means all the pictures relate to titles of songs or movies or something.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Trail?

1 - Woman walking in a Dress

> A dress can have a trail

2 - Flames

> Trail Blazing

3 - Paper Money/Cash (a US Dollar)

> Money Trail, or even paper trail

4 - Rolling of the eyes

> Rolling trail

5 - A windowed error message

> A data trail?  Or maybe a diagnostic message trail?

6 - Sleep/Snoring/Dream?

> Yeah...  I don't know... Trail of Dreams? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_of_Dreams_2010

Comment: Good answer. I was trying to fit trial but could only get 2. ... by fire,  5. .. and error. +1

Comment: @Tom this is the best of 5 answers I have majority fits for but none of them fill me with any confidence...  This is either a tough one or I'm going to be kicking myself hard later :)

Answer (score 0):

> The devil

1

> [The Devil Wears Prada](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458352/)

2

> Hell Flames hence ... the devil

3

> Sell your soul to the devil

4

> I got nothing.

5

> Internet explorer is the devil's tool.  (I have nothing here. I had to say something that fits.)

6

> [Sleeping with the Devil](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120146/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Comment: What about 4 and 5? This is not the answer..

Comment: I thought so...I just took a shot

Comment: Yes. It was a good try, though I had to say it wasn't the answer for other users to see it.